# Weird git message won't disappear from VSCode Source Control tab

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

[image]

I'm using VSCode to code an expo project (react native).
I accidentally made changes in the main branch, so I stashed changes, checked out to another branch (it happened to be behind main which I forgot), then popped.

Then I pushed those changes in a weird way and now this message won't disappear.

I even deleted the `minch` branch but it won't go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is not a warning or an information message, it is located in the input field where you type your commit messages.

Just select the text and delete it (press the `delete` key on your keyboard).

Comment: Wow, now I feel *really* stupid, thanks! :D
This totally should be the accepted answer.